# How I make scrollbar auto-scroll to a item in table

Tags: javascript

I have a table with scrollbar. How I make scrollbar auto-scroll to a item in table.
.

Comment: Isn't there a scrollTo mehod to use? I'm not at my normal place so i can't dig up the right reference.

Answer (score 0):

[optikalefxx](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6pzabpUmoc) helped me out with this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6pzabpUmoc

**HTML**

```
<p class="navigation">
    <h2><a href="#link1">Link 1</a> | <a href="#link2">Link 2</a> | <a href="#link3">Link 3</a> | <a href="#link4">Link 4</a></h2>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    // catch all clicks on a tags
    $("a").click(function() {
        // check if has hash
        if(this.hash) {
            // get rid of the # sign
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

            // get the position of the <a name>
            var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
            var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

            // scroll/animate to that element
            $("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop : toPosition
            },1500,"easeOutExpo");

            // don't do the jump
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(location.hash) {
        var hash = location.hash;
        window.scroll(0,0);
        $("a[href="+hash+"]").click();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you too.